# How do create large number of rows with a single sql statement in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

With a user model that `has_many :games` and a game model that `belongs_to user`, I want to create many games with one sql query using a postgresql database. So far I have tried

```
user=User.first
scores=[10,11,15,12] # a sample of a much larger array
values=scores.map{|s| "(#{Time.now},#{user.id},#{s})" }.join(",")
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO games (created_at,user_id, score) VALUES #{values}")
```

but I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "18"
LINE 1: ...(created_at, golfer_id, score) VALUES (2017-05-17 18:26:14 +...
                                                             ^
: INSERT INTO games (created_at, golfer_id, score) VALUES (2017-05-17 18:26:14 +1000,10,10),(2017-05-17 18:26:14 +1000,10,11),(2017-05-17 18:26:14 +1000,10,15),(2017-05-17 18:26:14 +1000,10,12)
from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@golf_lab/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `async_exec'
```

It looks like the format for the time is incorrect. I have tried creating the games without a created_at field, but postresql throws an error to the effect that the created_at field cannot be NULL.

How do fix this?

Comment: Try adding quotes to date `"('#{Time.now}',#{user.id},#{s})"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a quote around dates and to add the `updated_at` field.

```
values=scores.map{|s| "('#{Time.now}','#{Time.now}',#{user.id},#{s})" }.join(",")
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO games (created_at,updated_at, user_id, score) VALUES #{values}")
```